# "Property must be initialized" only with custom setter (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, class, oop, properties, jvm

I have the following class:

```
class Circle(radius: Double) {
    var radius: Double

    init {
        this.radius = radius
    }
}
```

So far everything works fine.

Now I define a custom setter for the `radius` property. It is identical to the setter that would be generated automatically if I did not specify one, am I right?

```
class Circle(radius: Double) {
    var radius: Double
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }

    init {
        this.radius = radius
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, I now get the compile error '**Property must be initialized**'.

How can this be? Why does this error only occur if I define a custom setter (which in this case is even identical to the standard setter) and although I initialize the radius property in the init block?

I know that I could solve the problem by adding an initializer to the `radius` property, like here:

```
class Circle(radius: Double) {
    var radius: Double = radius
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }
}
```

But I don't understand why I have to do that.